# Why does the name 'John' have an 'h' in it?

Tags: etymology, orthography, names, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I have always wondered this since I was little, and nobody seems to have asked or answered this before anywhere on the internet.  What is the origin of the 'h', and why is it still with us?

Comment: bad joke - Because the silent 'h' in John stands for hooker.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's a relic from previous versions of the name. From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=John&searchmode=none):

> **John** *masc*. proper name, mid-12c., from M.L. *Johannes*, from L.L. *Joannes*, from Gk. *Ioannes*, from Heb. *Yohanan* (in full *y'hohanan*) lit. "Jehovah has favored," from *hanan* "he was gracious."

Comment: So was the *Gospel of John* actually something else before 12c? Like *Yohanan*?

Comment: @JoseK, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_translations#Early_translations_in_Late_Antiquity

Answer (score 9):

It seems to be a remnant of the *h* in the Latin spelling *Johannes*, possibly via an abbreviation.

In some early documents, e.g. the [1292 Subsidy Rolls of London](http://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/names/english/london1292.html), *John* is most often abbreviated as *Joh'*, but occasionally you meet a non-abbreviated spelling such as *Jon*. And in the [Rutland Lay Subsidy of 1296](http://www.galbithink.org/names/rutland1296-7.txt), the name occurs as *John* unless it's a patronymic (*filius Johannis*). Ditto for the [1332 Lay Subsidy Rolls for Lincolnshire](http://www.s-gabriel.org/names/mari/LincLSR/GivJ5.html), but just a little bit later, the [1381 Suffolk Poll Tax](http://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/names/english/suffolk1381.pdf) mostly writes it out as *Johannes*, with a few odd cases (*Johanne*, *Johannis*), a couple where the -us ending is lost (*Johann*), and one "*Joh...*". Skipping ahead a few centuries, the [Registers of the Church of St. Mary's, Dymock, 1538-1600](http://medievalscotland.org/kmo/Dymock/dym_men.shtml) have quite a few variant spellings: *John* (788), *Jhon* (25), *Johne* (3), *Jon* (4), *Johan* (1), *Jonh* (1).

From this, I would tentatively conclude that (1.) the vernacular pronunciation of the name became a single-syllable "Jon" fairly early on, and (2.) the *John* spelling might have originally been a Latin-language abbreviation, but it came to be used as the standard vernacular spelling because it matched the vernacular pronunciation.

Answer (score 8):

From [behindthename](http://www.behindthename.com/name/john)

> English form of *Iohannes*, the Latin form of the Greek name Ιωαννης (*Ioannes*), itself derived from the Hebrew name יוֹחָנָן (Yochanan) meaning "YAHWEH is gracious".
>
> <sub>This name owes its popularity to two New Testament characters, both highly revered saints. The first was John the Baptist, a Jewish ascetic who was considered the forerunner of Jesus Christ. The second was the apostle John, who was also traditionally regarded as the author of the fourth Gospel and Revelation.</sub>
>
> <sub>This name was initially more common among Eastern Christians in the Byzantine Empire, but it flourished in Western Europe after the First Crusade. In England it became extremely popular: during the later Middle Ages it was given to approximately a fifth of all English boys.</sub>

it is visible that **h** was added in transition from Greek *Ioannes* to Latin *Iohannes*.

I know next to nothing of phonetics, however [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=John) states that

> M.L. Johannes is from L.L. Joannes

and in wikipedia article on Medieval Latin you can find a list of [orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Latin#Orthography) changes, some of which are:

> - *h* might be lost, so that *habere* becomes *abere*, or *mihi* becomes *mi* (the latter also occurred in Classical Latin); or, *mihi* may be written *michi*, indicating the *h* came to be pronounced as *k*. This pronunciation is not found in Classical Latin.
> - The loss of *h* in pronunciation also led to the addition of *h* in writing where it did not previously belong, especially in the vicinity of r, such as *chorona* for *corona*, a tendency also sometimes seen in Classical Latin.

Answer (score 3):

As @Robusto said, it came from the Hebrew *Yohanan*, but just to show where it [actually came from:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/John)

> contraction from Hebrew יוֹחָנָן (Johanan)

The word יוֹחָנָן  [comes from:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%9F#Hebrew)

> From the Hebrew phrase יהוה חנון (Yihoh Khanun, "Jehovah is gracious")